# Infusionsoft PHP CC info with Novak Solutions SDK

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am having issues getting a users credit card info using Novak Solutions Infusionsoft SDK. Both systems say that I can use a "Find by Field" query but I seem to get an error with the CC object.

So it would look something like this:

```
Infusionsoft_DataService::findByField(new Infusionsoft_CreditCard(), 'ContactId', 9 (the id), null, 0, false, null);
```

Response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [NoFieldAccess]Access denied to field CreditCard.CardNumber Attempted: 3 time(s).
```

The `DataService` seems to work with all object but the `Infusionsoft_CreditCard()` one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Infusionsoft API documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/), `CreditCard.CardNumber` field is not readable, Add access is only allowed.

To avoid the error throwing, the simplest fix is to pass the 6th parameter: array of `$returnFields`. For example:

`Infusionsoft_DataService::findByField(new Infusionsoft_CreditCard(), 'ContactId', 9, null, 0, ['Id', 'Last4', 'ContactId'], null);`

For another solution take a look at  [Infusionsoft_DataService.load()](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk/blob/master/Infusionsoft/DataService.php) method implementation, specifically lines 101 to 105.

`if(!$returnFields){
            $object->removeRestrictedFields();
            $returnFields = $object->getFields();
            $object->addRestrictedFields();
        }`

These lines either need to replace lines 40 to 42 in the same file (changing `findByField()` method implementation, and I'm just mentioning here it would be better to further refactor the code after that, abstracting these lines for multiple usages).

Or use them in your code (with needed updates) to get `$requiredFields` without read-restricted fields for further passing them to `Infusionsoft_DataService.findByField()` method as shown above.

One more useful reference is `Infusionsoft_CreditCard.removeRestrictedFields()` [method implementation](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk/blob/master/Infusionsoft/CreditCard.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the `Infusionsoft_CreditCard` object first then removing the restricted fields before passing it on to the query!

```
$CC = new Infusionsoft_CreditCard();
$CC->removeRestrictedFields();

// Now continue with your former query and use the above object.
Infusionsoft_DataService::findByField( $CC, 'ContactId', 9, null, 0, false, null);

// Or use the query method.
Infusionsoft_DataService::query( $CC, array( 'ContactId' => 9 ) );
```

This should return all the CC fields except the restricted ones.